# How to remove an item from the second drop down list when that item is selected in the first drop down list?

Tags: c#, asp.net

For this conversion application, when the user selects "decimal" from the first drop down list, I want the app to remove the "decimal" from the second drop down list, as it wouldn't make any sense to have that option. I used the items collection in the properties to fill in the items in the drop down list. Here is the code I have for the aspx.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace FirstAssignment
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void ddlSource_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
        }
        protected void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsValid)
            {
                String target = ddlTarget.SelectedItem.Value;

                if (ddlSource.SelectedValue == "Decimal") /// decimal to other formats
                {
                    int number = int.Parse(txtSource.Text);


                    if (target == "Binary")
                    {
                        String Base = Convert.ToString(number, 2);
                        lblOutput.Text = Base;
                        txtHistory.Text = number + " Decimal = " + Base + " Binary";

                    }
                    else if (target == "Hexadecimal")
                    {
                        String Base = Convert.ToString(number, 16);
                        lblOutput.Text = Base;
                        txtHistory.Text = number + " Decimal =  " + Base + " Hexadecimal";
                    }
                    else if (target == "Octal")
                    {
                        String Base = Convert.ToString(number, 8);
                        lblOutput.Text = Base;
                        txtHistory.Text = number + " Decimal =  " + Base + " Octal";
                    }

                } else if (ddlSource.SelectedValue == "Binary")  ///Binary to other formats
                {
                    String source = txtSource.Text;

                    if (target == "Decimal")
                    {
                        String Base = Convert.ToInt32(source, 2).ToString();
                        lblOutput.Text = Base;
                    }
                    else if (target == "Hexadecimal")
                    {
                        String Base = Convert.ToInt32(source, 2).ToString("X");
                        lblOutput.Text = Base;
                    }
                    else if (target == "Octal")
                    {
                        int Base = Convert.ToInt32(source, 2);
                        String Base1 = Convert.ToString(Base, 8);
                        lblOutput.Text = Base1;
                    }

                } else if (ddlSource.SelectedValue == "Hexadecimal")  ///Hexadecimal to other formats
                {
                    String source = txtSource.Text;

                    if (target == "Decimal")
                    {
                        String Base = Convert.ToInt32(source, 16).ToString();
                        lblOutput.Text = Base;
                    }
                    else if (target == "Binary")
                    {
                        int Base = Convert.ToInt32(source, 16);
                        String Base1 = Convert.ToString(Base, 2);
                        lblOutput.Text = Base1;
                    }
                    else if (target == "Octal")
                    {
                        int Base = Convert.ToInt32(source, 16);
                        String Base1 = Convert.ToString(Base, 8);
                        lblOutput.Text = Base1;
                    }

                }  else ///Octal to other formats
                {
                    String source = txtSource.Text;


                    if (target == "Decimal")
                    {
                        String Base = Convert.ToInt32(source, 8).ToString();
                        lblOutput.Text = Base;
                    }
                    else if (target == "Binary")
                    {
                        int Base = Convert.ToInt32(source, 8);
                        String Base1 = Convert.ToString(Base, 2);
                        lblOutput.Text = Base1;
                    }
                    else if (target == "Hexadecimal")
                    {
                        int Base = Convert.ToInt32(source, 8);
                        String Base1 = Convert.ToString(Base,16);
                        lblOutput.Text = Base1;
                    }
                }

            }




            txtHistory.Text += txtSource;
        }

        protected void btnClear_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtSource.Text = "";
            ddlSource.ClearSelection();
            ddlSource.SelectedValue = "--Select One--";
            ddlTarget.ClearSelection();
            ddlTarget.SelectedValue = "--Select One--";
            lblOutput.Text = "";
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Do it in the ddlSource_SelectedIndexChanged event.

Comment: I have added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60162355/5519709), please check.

Answer (score 0):

Do this in the ddlSource_SelectedIndexChanged event

```
protected void ddlSource_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    ddlTarget.Items.Remove(((Dropdown)sender).SelectedItem.Value));          
}
```

Comment: Getting the following error after adding the above line: `The type or namespace name 'ComboBox' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Ok. You are working on a web form. Wait ill update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [SelectedIndexChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindexchanged?view=netframework-4.8) event, also make sure that `ddlSource` and `ddlTarget` have `AutoPostBack="true"` attribute.

```
protected void ddlSource_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((sender as DropDownList).SelectedValue == "Decimal")
    {
        ddlTarget.Items.Remove("Decimal");
        ddlTarget.DataBind();
    }
}
```